# ngdocs - how to document a module config and run block

Tags: angularjs, documentation, jsdoc3, grunt-ngdocs

I have recently started using ngdocs in my angular application, and I am stumped on how to sensibly document a modules config and run block.

I have this currently:

```
/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name app.core
 * @description
 * # app.core
 * This module defines the core application behaviour such as routing and translation services.
 */
angular.module('app.core', ['pascalprecht.translate',
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'AuthService', function($rootScope, $state, AuthService){
    //How to document this?
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams){
      if(toState.name !== 'login' && !AuthService.isLoggedIn()){
        var requestedState = {
          toState: toState,
          toParams: toParams
        };
        $state.go('login', requestedState);
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  }]);
```

Which outputs the module app.core in the docs as expected. But how can I document the run block? I am struggling to find any examples out there.

Thanks

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I presume you meant how you can document the bit under `//How to document this?` specifically the stateChangeStart?

Answer (score 0):

Try amending `@name`, i.e.:

`* @name app.core.run:AuthService`

P.S.:
I’ve been hunting for better @ngdoc types.  I would prefer it if we could use `@ngdoc config` or `@ngdoc run`, but so far I haven’t found these to be valid types.